# Use Euro symbol in MySql query

Tags: mysql, concatenation

How to use euro symbol in MySql `concat()` function?

Below I tried but it prints only text whatever.

> SELECT CONCAT(tab1.amount,'&euro') FROM tab1

Anyhelp appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&euro` HTML entity can't be used in MySQL. Use [standard ascii sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) instead:

```
SELECT CONCAT(tab1.amount, _ucs2 0x20AC) AS t
FROM tab1;
```

*Note:* `_ucs2` is for using [UCS-2 Unicode Encoding](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-ucs2.html)